# css stretch background image with top and bottom padding

Tags: css, background-image, margin, padding

I want the background image for a page to stretch to the full width and height. The challenge here is that it should leave out an area of 48 px at the top as well as at the bottom (those are header and footer areas and we don't want this image to hide behind that). Also, I am trying to do it with css only (no javascript or client side code). CSS3 is ok.

Here is where I am so far. I have been able to get the top margin:

```
 background-image: url('images/image1.png')
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
background-position:  center 48px;  
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using background-size, I would make a div with an image inside of it, and position it absolutely to the window, and then position everything you want on top of it relative, with a higher z-index.  Background-size css property is not supported in the earlier versions of IE, only IE9+.  Here is a tiny example:

```
<body>
    <div class="bg-image">
        <img src="images/image-1.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>this is your content</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then for CSS:

```
.bg-image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto; /*or 100%*/
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 48px 0px;
}

.bg-image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer served me just right because I already had the header and footer at a higher z-index. Guess going the img route is the easier solution. Still wonder though if we can apply bottom padding or margin to a background image.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this slightly differently - I would three `<div>`s stacked on top of each other, with the middle one having the background image applied like you wanted. That way, you could make the first and third `<div>`s 48px tall, or whatever height you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both header and footer on a wrapper div which has:

```
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  height:48px;
  background:(use solid color to cover your body background )
}
```

It would look like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <header>
..
..
 </header>
</div
```

Same thing with the footer.

Then make sure both header and footer are set like this:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width:980px ( whichever is your width )
```

Voila.